# How can I see/can I know what posts I need to send?

Tags: python, post, webforms, urllib

I have a webform that I want to submit using python. I know from looking at the source code that to send a file to the site I need to use 'FILE'. However, when I run the following code on that site:

```
url = "http://mascot.proteomics.dundee.ac.uk/cgi/search_form.pl?FORMVER=2&SEARCH=MIS"
values = {'FILE' : '/homes/ndeklein/test.mzML'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

The page contains the following:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Fatal Error</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Fatal Error</H1>
<P><B>must specify search type</B><P></BODY></HTML>
```

So I must give the file type. However, I have no idea how to find out what name the file type has in the webform. If I had a list of everything being send when doing it by hand I could probably figure it out. So how can I find out what POST uses for the file type, or how can I get a list of everything being send by the webform?

Comment: We'll have a hard time providing valuable input if we can't even see the form you're trying to automatically submit data to.

Comment: @Niek does the form tries to upload the file?

Comment: @BunnyRabbit Yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have access to the form in a browser. When your browser submits that form you can see what is submitted using the browsers developer tools (Firebug Addon for Firefox).